# Diferença entre Comparator e Comparable

Tags: java

Em Java, qual é a diferença entre essas duas interfaces, Comparator e Comparable? Quando usar uma ou outra?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Comparable:** Se você tem controle sobre o código-fonte da classe, você pode implementar essa interface nela para definir uma estratégia de ordenação padrão. Exemplo: se você tem uma classe de *Pessoa*, você pode implementar *Comparable* nela definindo uma ordenação pelo nome, pois é um critério muito utilizado para ordenar *Pessoas*, logo, pode ser o padrão (natural).

**Comparator:** É útil quando você precisa criar ordenações personalizadas. Você pode ter uma classe com uma estratégia de ordenação padrão (implementando *Comparable* nela) e em situações que forem necessárias ordenar de forma diferente, criar *n* classes que implementam *Comparator* para atender a esses casos que a ordenação padrão da classe não atenda. Seguindo o exemplo da classe *Pessoa* que ordena por padrão pelo nome, pode acontecer que em uma situação específica você precise ordenar, por exemplo, *Pessoas* por idade decrescente e pelo nome da mãe. Aí você implementa um *Comparator* para esta classe.

Resumo:

- Você tem uma estratégia padrão de ordenação e pode alterar a classe? **Comparable** é uma boa opção.
- Você precisa definir várias estratégias de ordenação ou não tem condições de definir a estratégia padrão de ordenação na classe porquê não pode alterá-la? **Comparator**.

Answer (score 0):

O **Comparable** permite que você diga uma regra de comparação para a classe que implementar essa interface, como uma espécie de regra padrão ou regra oficial, enquanto que se você quiser fugir dessa regra padrão, você pode criar suas classes comparadoras, que vão extender a classe **Comparator** fazendo cada uma a sua própria regra.